# Azure giving 403(forbidden) with android(API level 19)

Tags: android, azure

I've just started using Azure storage in my Android project. It is working fine on devices of API level greater than 19. But when I am trying to get an media attachment on device of API level 19(4.4.4) , it is giving 403 error(forbidden). I am using GET with HttpURLConnection to get data. 
How should I solve this issue? Should I pass something extra with my  get request?